# Passing data string to HTML cover in wkhtmltopdf

Tags: html, pdf-generation, wkhtmltopdf

I know wkhtmltopdf lets you pass data to HTML headers and footers using built-in query strings (page, frompage, topage, webpage, section, subsection, date, isodate, time, title, doctitle, sitepage, sitepages) and custom query strings with `--replace`.

I want to do the same thing with my `cover.html`. Is it possible to pass strings to a HTML cover using only wkhtmltopdf?

I tried the same method I used with headers and footers. It won't work. The data passed is always "undefined".

Answer (score 0):

wkhtmltopdf has an option `--run-script` which runs an additional javascript after the page is done loading. There are many ways of passing command line strings to the HTML. One of them is described below.

You can create a class, e.g. "my_class", inside the HTML:

```html
<p class="my_class"></p>
```

In the command line you can pass a string, e.g. "my_string", via javascript:

```bash
... cover cover.html --run-script "var e = document.getElementsByClassName('my_class'); e[0].textContent = 'my_string'" ...
```

In this case, the text content of the HTML element will be replaced by "my_string".